# What is the word for cronyism based on favoring an ethnic or religious background (not friendship)

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word, similar to *cronyism* and *nepotism*, that means “favoring people of a particular culture, religion, or ethnicity, regardless of their expertise”.

I was thinking *racism*, but I’ve always understood that as the belief that one race is superior to another. But cronyism isn’t the belief that your friends are superior to others. They just get preferential treatment. So racism doesn’t seem right.

For example: a Russian person gets appointed as a hiring manager, and over the next year 60% of the staff have been replaced by Russians.

Comment: Racial/Ethnic partiality? Racial/Ethnic bias?

Comment: @mikhailcazi Those definitely work, but I was wondering about a single word (like nepotism is for familial bias)

Comment: No single word is striking me yet :P

Comment: Although, I think ethnic nepotism, as @user49727 says, is perfect. It's the official term: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethnic_nepotism

Comment: @mikhailcazi Reading the wikis, ethnic nepotism and tribalism seem to be the same thing if you're willing to stretch the definition of a contemporary 'tribe' (which, I think, is debated). Given that though, I think ethnic nepotism is a little more clear (but it has so many syllables!)

Comment: Why don't you just say 'ethnep' if it's too long? ;)

Comment: This is similar to http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91084/is-there-a-word-similar-to-racism-when-referring-to-an-ethnic-group-rather-tha .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This type of *ethnocentric* prejudice is referred to as:

***in-group favouritism***

***ethnic nepotism***

or my personal favourite ***tribalism***

Some informative links:

[***ingroup bias***](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-ingroup-bias.htm)

[***ethnic nepotism***](https://lesacreduprintemps19.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/j-p-rushtons-theory-of-ethnic-nepotism.pdf)

[***tribalism***](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tribalism)

Edit: If you are looking for single words only ***ethnocentrism*** itself is an alternative.

Comment: I do like `tribalism`

Comment: Another related term is 'collective (or group) narcissism' which I think is also quite apt.

Answer (score 1):

Besides previous suggestions, also consider *[chauvinism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chauvinism)*,  “(pejorative) Unwarranted bias, favoritism, or devotion to one's own particular group, cause, or idea”; *[jingoism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jingoism#Noun)*, “Excessive patriotism or aggressive nationalism especially with regards to foreign policy”; and  *[nationalism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nationalism#Noun)* “Patriotism; the idea of supporting one's country and culture”.

Answer (score 0):

The word you're looking for is *prejudiced*.  While a generic word, prejudice comprises favoritism, or its opposite, to any particular group of people who have something in common.  To be prejudiced is simply to pre-judge some group of people as being either inherently unworthy of favor or worthy of favor.

A prejudiced person gives little or no consideration to a person's actual worthiness (e.g., objective criteria such as experience, brightness, motivation, integrity, character and the like), but to an assumed worthiness based on nationality, language, accent, family ties, friendship ties, skin color, religion, sex, sexual orientation, age, subculture, schools attended, socio-economic status, and how a person parts his or her hair!  In other words, virtually any factor by which someone can be adjudged different and therefore better or worse than someone else.

Based on what I've said above, please do not infer that prejudice is always a bad thing; it is not.  I'm prejudiced against prejudiced people for whom the basis of their prejudice is one or more of the above factors I've listed.  Furthermore, I'm prejudiced against evil, wicked, violent, intolerant, greedy, selfish, lazy, hateful, bigoted, narrow-minded, overly irreverent, rude, crude, and lewd people.  And the list goes on.